# Widget with separate settings activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been following [THIS](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-app-widget-with-configuration-activity/) tutorial to create a Widget with configuration activity. When you add the widget to the homescreen it shows the settings activity and changes the widget look accordingly. But after that you can't change the look.
However I would like for the settings activity to be separate, meaning that there is an icon in the apps menu and when you press it, settings show up and you can change the widget look.
I've tried changing the Main launcher in Android Manifest to the Settings activity, but it doesn't work. How can this be created?

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.appwidgetclockconfiguration"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".WidgetConfigurationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="AnalogClockWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you paste your manifest file?

Comment: The configuration activity has to be called from the widget itself. If you call it from the app drawer how would it know which widget to configure? Unless you force the user somehow to add just one instance of a widget to the home screen (not really what widgets are made for)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
<activity
    android:name=".WidgetConfigurationActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: No and why should it? That doesn't make sense because you need a to call the configuration activity from the widget itself. How else would the config activity know which widget to configure?
You need to add a button to the widget that calls the config activity.